# Print specified page, update DB MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the following code:

```
<iframe onscroll ="caise4.php" name="frame4"></iframe>
<input type= "submit" onclick ="frames['frame4'].print()" value = "WATER/ELECTRICITY" id = "id4"></a>
```

This would allow me to print a different page when the button/frame is clicked.
And i have the following PHP code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['frame4'])){
 $SQL_1 = "INSERT INTO `tick4` (`ticket_id`, `ticket_date`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
 $result_1 = mysqli_query($db, $SQL_1);

 $SQL_2 = "UPDATE v_attente_service AS vas 
            JOIN (SELECT COUNT(ticket_id) AS cnt FROM tick4) AS ti 
            SET vas.NOMBATTE = ti.cnt
            WHERE vas.CODESERV=4";
$result_2 = mysqli_query($db, $SQL_2);

}
?>
```

When the user clicks, a new row needs to be inserted in the table "tick4". Then "NOMBATTE" in "v_attente_service" is updated.

Basically, when the user prints a ticket, the number of tickets is updated, and the number of people waiting in the queue is also updated.

The problem I have: I get redirected to the page preview, but nothing is displayed there. Also, nothing gets updated in my tables.
I am using phpMyAdmin by the way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try running the update directly in PHPMyAdmin and see if you get any error messages.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes i first ran it on phpMyAdmin, when it worked, i copied it to the page where i'm working!